# Rectangle motion seems to stutter

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write a program which will display a strip of icons at the top of your screen for quick access of files. For early testing I'm drawing a rectangle and I'm having it follow a temporary location to check how smoothly it moves across the screen.

```
    public Pen defaultPen;

    public PointF tempLocation = new PointF( 10, 10 );

    public Timer updateTimer = new Timer();

    public DesktopStrip()
    {
        this.Size = new Size( Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 88 );
        this.Top = 10;

        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler( PaintDesktop );

        this.SetStyle( ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                       ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                       ControlStyles.UserPaint, true );

        this.defaultPen = new Pen( Color.White );

        this.updateTimer.Interval = 30;
        this.updateTimer.Tick += new EventHandler( anim_Tick );
        this.updateTimer.Start();
    }

    private void anim_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        tempLocation.X++;

        Refresh();
    }

    private void PaintDesktop( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.None;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;

        g.DrawRectangle( defaultPen, new Rectangle( (int)tempLocation.X, (int)tempLocation.Y, 64, 64 ) );
    }
```

My issue is that when it moves across the screen, I can see it stutter at points and I need it to be as smooth as possible. Is there anything I'm missing or that I could change?

I've tried using invalidate instead of refresh but it doesn't change anything visually.

Would there be an alternative way to do this rather than using winforms? Something that is possibly more animation friendly?

**EDIT:** I have changed the anim_Tick method to incorporate interpolation as such:

```
tempLocation.X = (float)Lerp( tempLocation.X, moveLoc.X, 0.05 );
```

and my interpolation method is:

```
public double Lerp( double value1, double value2, double amount )
{
    value1 = value1 + ( value2 - value1 ) * amount;

    return value1;
}
```

I have also changed the timer interval to 30ms. I can still see a stutter at points in the motion though..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is ticks.

You are asking the UI to refresh the position every 1 ms. That is WAY too often. The time it takes to calculate the offsets and reach actual rendering code would most likely take 5 if not 10 times longer. Consider using interpolated positions between your updates and space them out to say every 30 ms.

Basically you need to move the rectangle by a number of pixels per second. You need to use a Lerp function to do this.

Here is a link to an [open source project](https://code.google.com/p/csharpgameprogramming/source/browse/trunk/Engine/Engine/Lerp.cs?r=8) that should help.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the changes and an outcome at the bottom.

Comment: Is it better or the same? Did you try to use different update intervals?

Comment: Any interval > 40~50 starts to get choppy. The stuttering seems to lessen for intervals < 30 but as for the interpolation result, to me it doesn't stutter as much but it does move differently (slows up and slows down) which could blanket the stuttering that I saw

Comment: I just moved the interpolation into a BackgroundWorker and then called RunWorkerAsync (inside the anim_Tick method before Refresh()) whenever the worker isn't busy. This looked like it had an effect but I don't feel as if it's necessary to have a thread handling this..